# Missing Maven plugin

Tags: java, scala, maven

I'm trying to buils [terasort](https://github.com/ehiggs/spark-terasort).

When I run `mvn install` as instructed in the README, I get this warning:

> [WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for net.alchim31.maven:scala-maven-plugin is missing. @ line 74, column 13

In Eclipse an error appears beside the first `<execution>` in the pom.xml:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
  <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <goals>
        <goal>compile</goal>
        <goal>testCompile</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
    <execution>
      <id>attach-javadocs</id>
      <goals>
        <goal>doc-jar</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
  <configuration>
    <sourceDir>src/main/scala</sourceDir>
    <jvmArgs>
      <jvmArg>-Xms64m</jvmArg>
      <jvmArg>-Xmx1024m</jvmArg>
    </jvmArgs>
  </configuration>
```

The error that comes with it says:

> Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: net.alchim31.maven:scala-maven-plugin:3.3.1:compile (execution: default, phase: compile)

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By adding all plugins under pluginManagement you can resolve `Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration` error from eclipse.

```
  <pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>plugin_1</plugin>
      <plugin>plugin_2</plugin>
      <plugin>plugin_3</plugin>
    </plugins>
  </pluginManagement>
```

To resolve warning message while running `maven install`. You have to add version of `scala-maven-plugin`

```
 <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
 <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
 <version>3.3.1</version>
```

So your pom.xml will look like this - https://git.io/vNaWM